# Connected groupoids and action groupoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, groupoids, reference-request

It is written in Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid, that any *connected groupoid* $A\rightrightarrows X$ is isomorphic to an *action groupoid*  $G\ltimes X$ coming from a transitive action of some group $G$ on $X$. I do not understand how to construct such a group $G$, and would be grateful for an explanation or a reference.

I think  that in general one cannot recover $G$ from the action groupoid $G\ltimes X$. Indeed, if $G$ acts *simply transitively* on $X$, then the action groupoid is given by the equivalence relation $X\times X$ on $X$, hence does not depend on $G$, provided that ${\rm Card}(G)={\rm Card}(X)$. Is this correct?

This question is a version of [my question at Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361254/connected-groupoids-and-action-groupoids)
to which I got no answers.

Comment: I answered on math.stack exchange.

Comment: This is easier than everyone is making it sound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what I wrote on Math Stack Exchange:

A connected groupoid *A* can be written as an action groupoid for many different groups *G*. All the groupoid determines is *H*, the group of automorphisms of any object in the groupoid, and the index of *H* in *G*, which is the cardinality of the set of objects of the groupoid. And any group *G* with subgroup *H* of the correct index, the action of *G* on the set of cosets of *H* has action groupoid isomorphic to *A*.

This is to be expected, because if we think of *H* as a one object groupoid and of *X* as an indiscrete groupoid (the set of objects is *X*, and there is a unique morphism between any pair of objects) then the original groupoid *A* is isomorphic to the product *H* × *X*, so the isomorphism class of *A* depends only on the group *H* and the cardinality of *X*.

As an extreme example of this, let *G* act on itself by translation and take the action groupoid. This has set of objects *G* and a unique morphism between every pair of elements. Notice all traces of the group structure of *G* are gone: the isomorphism class of this indiscrete groupoid only depends on the cardinality of *G*.

UPDATE 2: Here is a sloganized answer to the question: the **equivalence** class of a connected groupoid *A* is determined by the isomorphism class of the group *H* = Aut(*x*<sub>0</sub>); the **isomorphism** class of a category is given by the data of its equivalence class plus the number of isomorphic copies of each object in a skeleton.

UPDATE: Here is a proof of the claims above "UPDATE 2".

**Claim 1**: *A* is isomorphic to *H* × *X*.

*Proof.* Choose an object *x*<sub>0</sub> of *A*, identify *H* with Aut(*x*<sub>*0*</sub>) and choose arbitrary morphisms *a*<sub>*x*</sub> : *x*<sub>*0*</sub> → *x*. The isomorphism *H* × *X* → *A* is the identity on objects and sends a morphism (*h*, *u*) : *x* → *y* to the morphism *a*<sub>*y*</sub> *h a*<sub>*x*</sub><sup>-1</sup>. (Here *u* is the unique morphism in *X* from *x* to *y*.) The inverse *A* → *H* × *X* sends a morphism *a* : *x* → *y* to (*a*<sub>*y*</sub><sup>-1</sup> *a a*<sub>*x*</sub>, *u*) --same *u* as above.

**Claim 2**: For any group *G* with a subgroup *H* of index |*X*|, the action groupoid of *G* acting on the set *G/H* of cosets is isomorphic to *A*.

*Proof.* Both groupoids are isomorphic to *H* × *X*.

Comment: @Omar: You write: "Any group $G$ with subgroup $H$ of the correct index, the action of $G$ on the set of cosets of $H$ has action groupoid isomorphic to $A$".  How can one construct such an isomorphism?

Comment: @Mikhail: Pick a set of representatives for the cosets of _H_, and pick a bijection between those representatives and the objects of _A_. I can add more detail later when I'm at a computer with a real keyboard.

Comment: @Omar: Thank you, now we have a group $G$ and a action of $G$ on $X$. How can we define an isomorphism between $G\ltimes X$ and $A$? Please kindly add more details when you can.

Comment: I hope that is clear enough, @MikhailBorovoi. If not let me know. As you can see, the proof is pretty much just what Sam Cunningham wrote (only slightly generalized). If you want an explicit isomorphism between A and G/H, you can just compose the isomorphisms A -> H x X -> G/H given in the proof of Claim 1.

Answer (score 3):

In the $C^\infty$ case, the Lie groupoid is the action of an identity neighborhood of the Lie group. You can enlarge the action by enlarging $X$, but you may loose Hausdorff. 
This goes back to Palais.
See (and references therein):

- Franz W. Kamber, Peter W. Michor: Completing Lie algebra actions to Lie group actions. Electron. Res. Announc. Amer. Math. Soc. 10 (2004) 1-10.[(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/lie-completion.pdf)

Comment: See also my answer to the stackexchange question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361254

Answer (score 3):

Here is my stackexcnage answer.

Another way of looking at this is to use the equivalence of categories between covering morphisms of a groupoid $P$ and actions of $P$ on sets. (Recall that a covering morphism $p:G \to P$ is a groupoid morphism having unique path lifting. Not necessarily unique path lifting gives a *fibration of groupoids*.) Given an operation of $P$ on a set $X$ then the corresponding covering morphism may be written $P \ltimes X$, an action groupoid, and thought of as a semidirect product because it is a special case of the semidirect product for an action of a groupoid $P$ on a groupoid $H$. For this one needs a morphism of groupoids $\omega: H \to Ob(P)$, where the latter is thought of as a discrete groupoid, and an element $w: x \to y$ in $P$ gives a morphism of groupoids $w_*: \omega^{-1}(x) \to \omega^{-1}(y)$. One has to be precise on conventions to get all this right, which I won't do here.

So a groupoid $G$ has a representation as an action groupoid whenever you  are given a covering morphism $ G \to P$. This is closely related to Omar's answer, of course.

I'll add that more details of these ideas are in my book [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html).

Addition: May 19, 2013 Here is a version of Sam's nice argument but in the language of covering morphisms.

If $G$ is a group then its *universal cover* $p: T \to G$ is a covering morphism of groupoids such that $T$ is connected and has trivial vertex groups; this is determined by the action of $G$ on itself by left multiplication. 
The set of objects  of $T$ is bijective with the set $G$ and $T$ is the indiscrete groupoid  (also called tree groupoid) on its set of objects. (Note that if $S$ is a generating set for $G$ then $p^{-1}(S)$ is a graph, namely the Cayley graph of $(G,S)$.)

Now let $A$ be a connected groupoid with $X$ as its set of objects. Let $T$ be the indiscrete groupoid on $X$. Then for any object $x$ of $A$,  $A$ is isomorphic to $A(x) \times T$. But if $G$ is as above, then 
$$1 \times p: A(x) \times T \to A(x) \times G$$
is a covering morphism.

The next question is whether this argument can illuminate the case $A$ is a $\Gamma$-groupoid.

Answer (score 2):

Given a connected groupoid $A \rightrightarrows X$, pick a basepoint $x_0$ and a morphism $f_{x}: x \to x_0$ for each object $x\in X$. We also need to choose a group structure $(X,.)$ on $X$. Let $G_0 = Aut(x_0)$, and set $G = G_0 \times X$ (as a group).

Then $G$ acts on $X$ by $(g,x) \ast y = x.y$.

Define an isomorphism $\Phi$ from $G \ltimes X$ to $A \rightrightarrows X$ by

$\Phi(y \xrightarrow{(g,x)} x.y)=f_{x.y}^{-1} \circ g \circ  f_y$.

This is compatible with composition: If we have morphisms in $G\ltimes X$

$y \xrightarrow{(g,x)} x.y \xrightarrow{(h,w)} w.x.y$,

then applying $\Phi$ gives

$f_{w.x.y}^{-1} \circ h \circ  f_{x.y} \circ f_{x.y}^{-1} \circ g \circ  f_y = f_{w.x.y}^{-1} \circ hg \circ  f_y = \Phi(y \xrightarrow{(hg,x.y)} w.x.y)$

as required.

Comment: In any case, I think what is written on the wikipedia page is wrong. They seem to want to set $G$ to be $G_0$. But if you have a connected groupoid with no automorphisms, this is not correct (in this case you should just take $G$ to be some group structure on $X$ and use the translation action).


Comment: These are some of the groups you can use, but in general you don't need $G$ to be a product, just to have a subgroup isomorphic to $G_0$ with index $|X|$.

Comment: Sure, I never claimed this was the only way. This was just the first construction that came to mind.

Comment: But, I agree, your answer is much clearer.

Comment: @Sam: Thank you for detailed answer! Unfortunately, I cannot accept two answers, otherwise I would accept your answer as well...

Answer (score 0):

The [post by John Baez
in the *$n$-Category Café*](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/02/m13.html)
gives a nice example of how the the Matthieu Group $M_{12}$
can be presented more simply using a groupoid called $M_{13}$.